# The annotation @PersistenceUnit is disallowed for this location

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc

As other persons, I have the problem:

> **"The annotation `@PersistenceUnit` is disallowed for this location"**.

My `persistence.xml` looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="XCCAdminUnit">
          <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDataSource</jta-data-source>

          <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.LockTimeout" value="30000" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.TransactionIsolation" value="read-committed" />
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="none" />
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.UpdateManager" value="operation-order" />
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My code:

```
package XCCAdminServlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.annotation.Resource.AuthenticationType;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class XCCAdminMain
 */
@WebServlet({"/XCCAdminMain", "/xcc-admin/rest/query", "/xcc-admin/test/query"})
@Resource(name = "jdbc/MyDataSource", type = javax.sql.DataSource.class, shareable = true, authenticationType = AuthenticationType.CONTAINER)
public class XCCAdminMain extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "XCCAdminUnit")
  /**
   * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
   */
  public XCCAdminMain() {
    super();
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/{param}")
  public Response getQuery(@PathParam("param") String msg) throws ServletException {
    return Response.status( 200 ).entity( "Get Request received, queryparam: " + msg ).build();
  }



}
```

What can I do to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `@PersistenceContext` annotation to inject the `EntitiyManager` bean into your servlet. This annotation has a `unitName`attribute, you can set it as follows:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "XCCAdminUnit")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Comment: Damn, that helped. Thank you very much!

Comment: U r welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer, please :)

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "XCCAdminUnit")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

So, `@PersistenceUnit` annotation must inject `javax.persistence.EntityManager` bean.

Comment: PersistenceUnit is used to annotate an EntityManagerFactory, not an EntityManager.

Comment: Actually, `EntityManager` is always injected with `@PersistenceContext` annotation which in turn has a `unitName` attribute. So you should use `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "XCCAdminUnit")` to inject entity manager

Comment: VladimirVagaytsev now I get   "The annotation @PersistenceContext is disallowed for this location"..